# What is difference between bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl and bypassSecurityTrustUrl

Tags: angular, angular8, angular2-security

I went through angular documentation for both functions

[bypassSecurityTrustUrl](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustUrl) which says

> Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe style URL, i.e. a value that can be used in hyperlinks or `<img src>`

[bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrustresourceurl) which says

> Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe resource URL, i.e. a location that may be used to load executable code from, like `<script src>`, or `<iframe src>`.

both of the above is used to bypass security and trust.

I was bypassing the blob url for `<img src>` ,so before going through the documentation, my IDE (vscode) presented the above two functions, and I used `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` and my code was like...this.

component.ts

```
    this.fileService.getFileBlobUrl(imgsrc).subscribe(url => {
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl
      user.bloburl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    });
```

component.html

```
    <img [src]="user.bloburl" class="avatar" alt="avatar">
```

as per documentation `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` should be working. but I used 'bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`

**and it is actually working!!!!**

So my question is what is the difference between those two functions. why two different function if any of them can be used?

Answer (score 7):

I'm actually creating pipes for `SafeValue`s and also got interested in that. So I started digging and here's what I found:

[DomSanitizationService:](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3cf2005a936bec2058610b0786dd0671dae3d358/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L174)`sanitization()`:

```js
      case SecurityContext.URL:
        const type = getSanitizationBypassType(value);
        if (allowSanitizationBypassOrThrow(value, BypassType.Url)) {
          return unwrapSafeValue(value);
        }
        return _sanitizeUrl(String(value));
      case SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL:
        if (allowSanitizationBypassOrThrow(value, BypassType.ResourceUrl)) {
          return unwrapSafeValue(value);
        }
```

So here `unwrapSafeValue` function is called in both types, but below we have:

[DomSanitizationService:](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3cf2005a936bec2058610b0786dd0671dae3d358/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L196)

```js
  bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value: string): SafeUrl { 
    return bypassSanitizationTrustUrl(value); 
  }
  bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    return bypassSanitizationTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
```

So here are 2 different functions invoked, let's go deeper.

In [sanitization/bypass.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a2e890e4f7d01f0edd1c69ce5be61ef69318d9e4/packages/core/src/sanitization/bypass.ts) we can find:

```js
export function bypassSanitizationTrustUrl(trustedUrl: string): SafeUrl {
  return new SafeUrlImpl(trustedUrl);
}
export function bypassSanitizationTrustResourceUrl(trustedResourceUrl: string): SafeResourceUrl {
  return new SafeResourceUrlImpl(trustedResourceUrl);
}
```

and a few lines up we can find out that the only difference between them is in the returned class:

```js
class SafeUrlImpl extends SafeValueImpl implements SafeUrl {
  getTypeName() { return BypassType.Url; }
}
class SafeResourceUrlImpl extends SafeValueImpl implements SafeResourceUrl {
  getTypeName() { return BypassType.ResourceUrl; }
}
```

and because of

```js
if (actualType != null && actualType !== type) {
    // Allow ResourceURLs in URL contexts, they are strictly more trusted.
    if (actualType === BypassType.ResourceUrl && type === BypassType.Url) return true;
    throw new Error(
        `Required a safe ${type}, got a ${actualType} (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`);
  }
```

now we know that `ResourceUrl` is allowed everywhere where `Url` would be.

Comment: +1 for digging in.. but i dont't get it why google created two functions which actually does the same thing... lol.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to use bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl when I sanitize images or videos and bypassSecurityTrustUrl when I sanitize files with app content like pdf or word or excel.